# Host a web page by Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: azure, iis, dns, windows-server-2012-r2

I registered a Microsoft Azure free Trial account, and installed Windows Server 2012 R2. I am trying to host a website over there.

By following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbErPceKtjQ), I have added `test.addbba.com` (I own the domain `addbba.com`) to IIS Manager, created `index.html`. I also added items in DNS Manager. However, loading `http://test.addbba.com` returns `This page can't be displayed`, instead of showing `index.html`:

[image]

I doubt it is because of the `Alias (CNAME)`. At the moment, the `Fully qualified domain name (FQDN) for target host` is set `virtualmachine.`, which is the name of my VM; I don't know what else to write...

The VM has internet connection, such that `google` works. I also tried to added `test.softtimur.com` (I don't have the domain `softtimur.com`), it does not work either.

Could anyone help?

**Edit 1:**

Following the answer of Andrew, I added one rule, here are all the rules:

[image]

But The page still can't be displayed. I highly doubt it is because of DNS parameters... I make a clearer screen-copy:

[image]

Comment: Hello, there's really a lot of typing involved in this one, but have you considered Web App for the purpose of hosting a web site?

Comment: Do you want that test site to be publicly reachable or only from within that server?

Comment: @DusanBajic I want this test site to be publicly reachable.

Comment: @4c74356b41 I have not considered Web App, i definitely want to use windows server.

Comment: Bring up the command prompt on your local machine, and type `nslookup test.addbba.com`. You will see that it is a non-existent domain. You must add an entry for `nslookup.test.addba.com` in the domain name server.

Comment: `www.addbba.com` bought from `GoDaddy` is mine, and it is hosted in a Ubuntu server of `DigitalOcean`. So should I modify in `GoDaddy` or `DigitalOcean` or just the the DNS Manager of `Windows Server`? I just want to make `test.addbba.com` to show the content of `index.html`...

Comment: @SoftTimur I believe you will have to go to GoDaddy. You will need to add an A record for your "test" subdomain, pointing to the Public IP address of the virtual machine's network interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this problem, and it was because the Network Security Group attached to the Network Interface did not allow incoming requests on port 80.

Drill down to the network security group, and click on the inbound security rules. Most likely, it will just have one rule, called `allowRdp`

[image]

Click on "Add", and add a new rule called "allowHttp", for TCP over port 80.

If you also want to enable https, add another rule for port 443.

Answer (score 0):

The DNS zones you're creating on the VM won't be available to the internet as they're not delegated.  The zone "addbba.com" is hosted by ns1/2/3.digitalocean.com so that's where the public DNS record would need to be created.  It should be either an A record to the public IP of the VM's NIC or a CNAME to the cloudapp.net DNS name for the VM's NIC.

If you're just creating the DNS zones on the website's server for test purposes, then "virtualmachine." isn't the FQDN of the VM, it will end in cloudapp.net.  If it's just for a test then "localhost." should work.